# Saving day, date and start and end time in database after saving, editing or deleting in AlloyUI Scheduler

Tags: javascript, user-interface, scheduler, alloy-ui

How do I save endDate, startDate and the time into my database after saving and editing on Alloy UI Scheduler?

At the moment, I am only able to save "content"

Here is my code.

```html
var eventRecorder = new Y.SchedulerEventRecorder({
on: {
        save: function (event) {
            alert('Save Event:' + this.isNew() + ' --- ' + this.getContentNode().val());
        },
        edit: function (event) {
            alert('Edit Event:' + this.isNew() + ' --- ' + this.getContentNode().val());
        },
        delete: function (event) {
            alert('Delete Event:' + this.isNew() + ' --- ' + this.getContentNode().val());
            // Note: The cancel event seems to be buggy and occurs at the wrong times, so I commented it out.
//      },
//      cancel: function(event) {
//          alert('Cancel Event:' + this.isNew() + ' --- ' + this.getContentNode().val());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

sample right here :

```
 save: function(event) {
            alert('Save Event:' + this.isNew() + ' --- ' + this.getContentNode().val() + ' startdate : '+this.get('startDate') + ' enddate : '+this.get('endDate') );
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the start and end time by getting the [`startDate`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerEventRecorder.html#attr_startDate) and [`endDate`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerEventRecorder.html#attr_endDate) attributes of [`SchedulerEventRecorder`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerEventRecorder.html):

```
var eventRecorder = new Y.SchedulerEventRecorder({
  on: {
    save: function(event) {
      console.log(
        'startDate: ' + eventRecorder.get('startDate') +
        '\nendDate: ' + eventRecorder.get('endDate')
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a runnable example:

```js
YUI().use('aui-scheduler', function(Y) {

  var eventRecorder = new Y.SchedulerEventRecorder({
    on: {
      save: function(event) {
        alert(
          'startDate: ' + eventRecorder.get('startDate') +
          '\nendDate: ' + eventRecorder.get('endDate')
        );
      }
    }
  });

  var weekView = new Y.SchedulerWeekView();

  new Y.Scheduler({
    boundingBox: '#myScheduler',
    date: new Date(2013, 1, 4),
    eventRecorder: eventRecorder,
    render: true,
    views: [weekView]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/701826667a70997013605edcd37e92a6/raw/469fe1ae297e72a5a80eb9015003b7b04eac735e/alloy-ui-3.0.1_aui_aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/90be22de7f48c729b443af14796d91d3/raw/a9f35ceedfac7fc0559b121bed105eaf80f10bf2/aui-css_css_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<div id="wrapper" class="yui3-skin-sam">
  <div id="myScheduler"></div>
</div>
```